# How can access java class methods inside jstl tags

Tags: java, jstl

I'am using JSTL for jsp pages to display data. This is my code.

```
<c:set var ="input1" value="${event.eventData}"/>
<c:out value=" <%= stringCustomizer.stringTokernize(args1,0,10) %>" />
```

first argument(args1) of `stringTokernize()` method is, "input1" variable which I initialize above. How can I give that variable inside the `<%=%>` tag?

I tried couple of ways, but still getting invalid syntax.

`stringCustomizer` is a java class for customize my input string. In front end, I use that into customize my display data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a scriptlet inside a JSTL tag, consider using JSTL for the functions as well. See [this page](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/) for a quick example.

```
${ank:tokenize(event.eventData, 0, 10)}
```